# Did Cuba Benefit More Economically by Dealing with the Soviets

Tags: soviet-union, cuba

The Soviets arguably had a good reason to deal with Cuba as it led to them having an attacking point in the event of a hot war. However, the US are usually inclined to boost a country's economy up to create a new trading partner; that being said, they were pro-communist. Out of the two options, did Cuba benefit economically from its distrust of America?

Comment: Great question. I fear that the implied counterfactual, what-if-they-hadn't, is unanswerable.

Comment: @Aaron Brick: Perhaps not answerable with 100% certainty, but given the poor state of Cuba's economy (and every Soviet block economy) we could make a pretty darned good guess :-)

Comment: One thing is certain, crime rate would be much higher if they left in US sphere of influence, as is in other countries of Latin America. It should not be forgotten that Mafia had to flee from Cuba when Castro took over.

Comment: @rs.29: Why is that "certain"?  It seems just the opposite: the "crime" rate was much higher under Castro, because many more things - like speaking out against the government or being gay - became crimes.

Comment: @jamesqf Not really, there are crime statistics for most countries in the world (murder, violent crimes, sexual crimes ...) . Cuba is better in this regards then average (non-communist) Latin American country. As for political crimes, data varies depending on the source, but they are minuscule compared to other "traditional" types of crime. Average person on the street is not much interested in spreading either homosexual agenda or in regime change. Does who do not like Cuban system usually tend to flee (to US or other neighboring countries)

Comment: @rs.29:  "homosexual agenda"?  What world are you from?

Comment: @jamesqf This world, then fireworks :)